# How to pass credentials to bigquery from pyspark running on local machine

Tags: google-bigquery, pyspark, credentials

I have a locally running pyspark cluster and want to load data from big query.
I have generated the server-to-server json credentials file
Now how do I pass that to my code.
TIA

Comment: Please expand on your question. It sounds like you want to write your own python connector code to talk to BigQuery. If that is not the case, then consider using the BigQuery Connector like this: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Answer (score 0):

When I write code to talk to Google's APIs from a tool, I generate Service Account Credentials within the project I want to use, download them, and then initialize the client with those credentials.

From python, I would use `oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` to create the credentials, and then pass those credentials using the `credentials` keyword parameter to the apiclient constructor. Something like:

```
key_bytes = ... # read your downloaded key from somewhere
bigquery_service = discovery.build(
    'bigquery', 'v2',
    credentials=oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        '1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        key_bytes,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'],
        private_key_password='notasecret',
        user_agent=_CLIENT_USER_AGENT))
```

Then whenever you use bigquery-service, your credentials will be passed along.